# Vue data back to default value after an Ajax call

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I've been working on lots of forms on my Nuxt app, and sometimes after Axios call setting the data manually to override entered values seems to be a bad idea especially for big objects.

```
...
data(){

  return { 
   name : '',
  }

}
...

$axios.post('/users/create', name).then( resp =>{ 


   this.name = '' // changing it back to the initial value.


})
```

It's fine with a small object, but when it gets big it seems to be a task. Not sure if my curiosity is clear, but all I want to do is to make the data back to the initial value without refreshing the page.

Comment: Store a temporary value of the initial state of the object when the component mounted, and then loop that object and set each respective value accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `data object` in a `variable` and reset it using loop, once the `Axios` request get finished

```
const initialObject = {
 name : 'foo'.
 ...
}
...
data(){

  return {
    ...initialObject
  }

}
...

$axios.post('/users/create', name).then( resp => { 
   for (let key in this.$data) {
     this[key] = initialObject[key]
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a huge form or you don't want to clear one by one field

```
// Declaring the default form values
const defaultOtherForm = {
  name: null,
  age: 18,
}
...
data: () => ({
  form: {
    name: null,
    age: null
  },
  otherForm: Object.assign({}, defaultOtherForm)
})

// After ajax called. You can use "loop" to clear values dynamically
Object.keys(this.form).forEach((key) => this.form[key] = null)

// Another way. Declare initialized form values and override with initialized values after ajax called successful
this.otherForm = defaultOtherForm
```

But if you want to use "native reset" form. You can wrap by a form

```
// After ajax called. Just call reset() method via ref
this.$refs.userForm.reset()
```